# How can I implement this logic

Tags: javascript

I have object structure like below

```
var obj = {
   a : 1,
   b : [x,y,z],
   c : [0,1,3],
   d : ['%','-','+']
}
```

I want to convert that object to below format

```
{
  1 : {
     x : {
         0 : ['%','-','+'], // Last index remains as an array
         1 : ['%','-','+'],
         3 : ['%','-','+']
     },
     y : {
         0 : ['%','-','+'], // Last index remains as an array
         1 : ['%','-','+'],
         3 : ['%','-','+']
     },
     z : {
         0 : ['%','-','+'], // Last index remains as an array
         1 : ['%','-','+'],
         3 : ['%','-','+']
     }
  }
}
```

If there is one more property after `['%','-','+']` in above case, same process continues..

```
var v = {}/* Object of above */, keys = Object.keys(v), simplifiedColumns = {};
for (var i = 0, l = keys.length; i < l ; i++) {
        if (v[i] instanceof Array) {

        }else{
              simplifiedColumns[keys[i]] = simplifiedColumns[keys[i]] || {};
        }
}
```

Please suggest me to complete this logic.

Comment: Note that `Object.keys` returns the keys in an arbitrary order, so you should probably sort the keys lexicographically before starting.

Comment: If I sort the keys, then the order will be changed, right? my requirement is to generate it in tree view manner in order

Comment: The efficiency of an algorithm to do that will be k^n (very inefficient). Doing this on a large set of data will simply not work as a result.

Comment: You need to sort them according to some order. Objects in Javascript are ***unordered*** collections of key/value pairs, so you need to give them a defined order to make your output be well-defined

Comment: can `x` and `y` for instance refer to the same object?

Comment: are `x,y,z` objects or is it meant to be an array of strings?

Comment: @elclanrs - I found that error as well. I believe they are strings (but who knows).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an algorithm that works, but it will create only one object for i.e. `x`, `y` and `z` and refer to that same object.

Also, the following example assumes that the order of the keys (provided by `Object.keys()`) is the same as the order in which the object was defined. This will not always be the case, so the better solution would be to change your object to an array:

```
var obj = [
   {
        "key": "a",
        "value": 1
   },
   {
        "key": "b",
        "value": ["x","y","z"]
   },
   {
        "key": "c",
        "value": [0,1,3]
   },
   {
        "key": "d",
        "value": ['%','-','+']
   }
];
```

But anyway, here is the algorithm using the original object notation:

```
var obj = {
   a : 1,
   b : ["x","y","z"],
   c : [0,1,3],
   d : ['%','-','+']
};

var keys = Object.keys(obj);

//set tempObj to the last array
var tempObj = obj[keys[keys.length - 1]];

//traverse the rest of the keys backwards
for (var i = keys.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
    var key = keys[i];

    //create new empty object
    var newObj = {};

    //append "tempObj" to that object and using the keys that are in the current array
    //or if the property isn't an array, use the property itself as key
    if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
        for (var k = 0; k < obj[key].length; k++) {
            newObj[obj[key][k]] = tempObj;
        }
    } else {
        newObj[obj[key]] = tempObj;
    }
    //override tempObj with the new created object
    tempObj = newObj;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/r5Wck/)**

Btw, if you need separate, independent objects, you could change the line

```
newObj[obj[key]] = tempObj;
```

to something like

```
newObj[obj[key]] = copyObject(tempObj);
```

where `copyObject` is a function that creates a deep copy of an object. But I guess in that case, the performance will drop drastically since you are copying the same objects over and over again.

Comment: keys.sort() leading to unwanted results.. :( If I remove sort it is working fine for me...

Comment: @Exception When you remove the sort are relying on undefined behaviour which is just happening to work correctly in some implementations of Javascript. It probably won't work in most versions of Chrome, but it's not a bug in Chrome. It's happening because you are treating an object as if it has order. You should be able to rewrite your code a bit so that instead of an unordered object: `{a: 1, b: 2}` you have an ordered array of pairs: `[{a: 1}, {b: 2}]`. Then you can get well-defined behaviour in all Javascript engines.

Comment: @Paulpro I don't understand. Why should `sort()`, applied to an array, cause any problems?

Comment: @Exception what exactly are these unwanted results that you get?

Comment: adding first value to the second object value instead of adding second to first when sorted. Because second will occupy the second place after sort.

Comment: @Exception I still don't understand. Do you have the keys "a", "b", "c", "d", etc. and do you want them to be nested deeper inside the resulting object as further they are in the alphabet? Then `sort()` should work, since it sorts an array lexicographically. You could modify my fiddle with your actual data. Maybe it becomes clearer to me if I see your code.

Comment: They are not always a,b,c.. they can be any

Comment: Ok, so you might have an object that looks like `{"foo" : {..}, "bar" : {...}, "yoo" : {...}}` and you want the properties to be processed in that very order as they are defined in the object. Right? The problem is, that afaik the order of your keys is not guaranteed. So the only way that remains would be to follow Paulpro's suggestion and use an array instead of an object.